# Agregar input text a formularios sin ID

Tags: jquery

Quisiera saber como podría agregar inputs a cualquier formulario con pulsar su botón (add) de cada formulario.
La idea es que el usuario pueda agregar mas campos si los requiere y que cuando presione "save changes", envíe todo serializado (incluyendo los nuevos campos que se agregan) de el formulario especifico.

En la pagina tengo un div que muestra lo generado en el .js

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div id="formulario"></div>
    <script src="formu.js"></script>  
</body>
```

En el "formu.js" tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    html="";   
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html='<form  method="post">';
    html = html + '<input type="text"  name="actividad" value="">';
    html = html + '<input type="text"  name="meta" value="">';
    html = html + '<button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button>';
    html = html + '<input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes">';
    html = html + '</form>';
    html = html + '<br>';
    $('#formulario').append(html);
}

    $(".update_form").click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "doStuff.php",
            data: $(this).parent().serialize(), 
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir un binding al botón de añadir e insertar un nuevo input cada vez que se presiona.

Me sorprende la pregunta dado que tu ejemplo para manejar el envío es algo muy similar.

El código quedaría así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    html="";   
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    html='<form  method="post">';
    html = html + '<div class="inputs">'
    html = html + '<input type="text"  name="actividad" value="">';
    html = html + '<input type="text"  name="meta" value="">';
    html = html + '</div>'
    html = html + '<button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success add_field">+</button>';
    html = html + '<input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes">';
    html = html + '</form>';
    html = html + '<br>';
    $('#formulario').append(html);
}

    $(".add_field").click(function() {
      $(this).parent("form").children(".inputs").append('<input type="text" name=data[] value="" />')
    })

    $(".update_form").click(function() { 
        console.log($(this).parent().serialize())
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "doStuff.php",
            data: $(this).parent().serialize(), 
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formulario"></div>
```